# Ubuntu 16.04 crash. How do I recover?

Tags: crash

While I was doing my project which consists of OpenCV programming, everything crashed and I can not log into Ubuntu. It shows me the screen below. Even when I try the options given, it does not lead me back to my normal Ubuntu OS. Please help, I have important project files inside there that are due.

[image: Recovery page]

Comment: Give more details about the issue you are facing.

Answer (score 1):

About your issue:

- Keep Calm, if you didn't do anything else, your files are in the hard drive.
- You can read more about your situation here: [How do I recover documents from a broken Ubuntu installation?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/77666/how-do-i-recover-documents-from-a-broken-ubuntu-installation)
- You can use a Live CD o Live USB to extract/copy/recover/backup your files to another hard drive or maybe a USB drive, here is how to do it, this works for Windows and Ubuntu, there are minimal differences: [How to Back Up Data From a Computer That Won’t Boot](https://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-back-up-data-on-your-computer-that-wont-boot/)
- Also you can try to repair your installation, here is how: [Repairing broken installation from Live USB without losing data](https://askubuntu.com/questions/726071/repairing-broken-installation-from-live-usb-without-losing-data)

Hope this helps, good luck!